# Не отображается favicon на проекте с использованием react js

Tags: reactjs, favicon

Пишу свой свой сайт-портфолио на react js и хочу добавить favicon.
В папку public закинул svg картинку, назвал favicon.ico
В index.html прописал -  
Но favicon не отображается на сайте когда я запускаю проект через npm start.
index.html и favicon.ico находятся в одной папке public, проект создавался через react create app.
Подскажите с чем может быть ошибка...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите с чем может быть ошибка...

Сам Реакт при инсталляции вот так вписывает `favicon.ico`.

```html
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Да, все так. Пробовал так писать, но результат тот же... Поэтому стал перебирать другие варианты, проблема в чем то другом

Comment: @FilimonovAlexey, просто сгенери весь проект еще раз через `npx create-react-app my-app`. Потом убери лишнее, добавь нужное. Замени саму иконку на свою...